# ¿Cual es el mejor lugar para guardar una contraseña dentro de una app Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una app y necesito consumir un WebService, antes de realizar el envío debo encriptar la información con una contraseña que solo el servidor y la app móvil conocen, esta contraseña me ayudará para poder encriptar y desencriptar el mensaje del servidor. ¿Cual sería el mejor lugar para guardar la contraseña? De tal manera que si alguien quiere hacer ingeniera inversa con el APK, la contraseña no sea visible y no pueda leer los mensajes del servidor.

Comment: Bajo que motivo piensas guardar la contraseña en el móvil ? En todo caso debería estar en tu Base de Datos, la contraseña sólo brinda el acceso hacia la cuenta y algunas transacciones.

Comment: @marlonpya edite mi pregunta amigo, gracias por responder

Comment: La app no debe guardar la contraseña, debes de guardar el id del usuario o el modelo para hacer las consultas, pero todo esto una vez q halla iniciado sesión. Si deseas restringir algo deberías mandarle una variable al aplicativo para que se haga cargo de ello, eso ya es programación.

Comment: La contraseña será utilizada para generar una cadena encriptada

Comment: Esa cadena siempre suele ir a una Base de datos.

Comment: en tu aplicación android puedes hacer uso de SQLite

Comment: @Leo se esa contraseña se usa para obtener información muy sensible no es recomendable tenerla en el dispositivo. Si no es así puedes guardarla en preferencias, un archivo o una base de datos, incluso enviarla a un WebService, pero debes hacer uso de encriptación.

Comment: @Leo ten cuidado con la información que guardas por ejemplo lo que comenta Felix Beeb, si conviertes a Hash SHA1 tu string obtendrías : 8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964 pero cualquiera puede encontrar con facilidad el valor real de la "contraseña encriptada" 12345

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys si es para obtener información, donde me recomiendas guardarla?. Gracias por responder. Necesito esa contraseña para intercambiar mensajes con el servidor

Answer (score 2):

Tu contraseña debe ser guardada en tu **Base de datos** almacenada en tu WS y suponiendo que unirás tu app android con el webservice mediante PHP puedes guardar la contraseña en formato SHA1 y así se guardará **encriptada** en tu base de datos, por ejemplo tu clave es `12345` en la base de datos se guardará como `8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964`

*Nota:* si quieres indagar mas en el tema mira [aquí](http://www.desarrolloweb.com/wiki/como-agregar-seguridad-a-una-clave-web-con-sha1.html) este enlace para que entiendas mas el tema.

Comment: Dentro de mi app android, en que lugar debo guardar la contraseña de forma segura? SharePreferences? Sqlite? un Archivo dentro de la app? De tal manera que no pueda ser leída si se hace ingeniería inversa sobre el APK

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a un tipo de "login" si es asi la clave se guarda en la base de datos y cuando tu app desee consumir datos de la base de datos comparara la clave de ingreso con la base de datos y ahi vera si te da acceso ... @Leo